# What are the default openSUSE 13.1 user groups?

Tags: xorg, users, opensuse, startx

I just installed openSUSE 13.1, and I can't even start X on boot.
I have to switch to another tty and type `startx` (after I set suid for xorg).
On top of this, I can barely do anything without root privileges (like shutdown from the GUI)

I believe it is because my user is only a memeber of the `users` group, and I know the default is more groups.

What are the default groups so I can add my user to them?

Comment: If this is a default install, then you might be better served on openSUSE mailing lists - see the [User/Support section](http://lists.opensuse.org/) or even better in [their bugzilla](https://bugzilla.novell.com).

Comment: I'm only part of the users group and I get X on every login...what is your default runlevel?

Answer (score 0):

The users group is the only group really required, these days most desktop environments / window managers use [polkit(policy kit)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit) to control who can perform actions such as shutdown and mounting flash drives etc without root. Generally polkit is configured by default to allow local users (those not remoted in through ssh etc) to perform these actions.

Some desktop environments such as enlightenment didn't launch a polkit authentication agent by default in openSUSE 13.1 or the authentication agent that is launched isn't currently installed. My openSUSE 13.2 machine has the packages, polkit-gnome, mate-polkit and polkit-kde-agent-1 each are polkit agents that you can run at startup to register your session.

I would expect that on kde and gnome this should work out of the box, if not you should create a bugreport on the openSUSE bugzilla, if you are using a different DM/WM try running one of the above agents and see if that resolves your issues, there is a chance that your DE/WM does not yet support polkit in which case you are going to struggle to do most of these things it is hard to provide more specific answers to your questions without knowing the DE, if you tell me i will try to update this answer accordingly